# Issues with attempting to use cardslib

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to use the cardslib library found here, https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib. I had a hard time trying to add this to my project, and the only way I could figure out how to was to just copy and paste the files into my project, and change all the package names to match my project. The issue is that during runtime the following error is generated:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nick.simplequiz.paid/com.nick.simplequiz.paid.statistics}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.nick.simplequiz.paid.view.CardView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.nick.simplequiz.paid.view.CardView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
    at com.nick.simplequiz.paid.statistics.onCreate(statistics.java:41)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
    ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    ... 22 more
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class com.nick.simplequiz.paid.component.CardShadowView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at com.nick.simplequiz.paid.view.BaseCardView.initView(BaseCardView.java:153)
    at com.nick.simplequiz.paid.view.BaseCardView.init(BaseCardView.java:125)
    at com.nick.simplequiz.paid.view.BaseCardView.<init>(BaseCardView.java:101)
    at com.nick.simplequiz.paid.view.CardView.<init>(CardView.java:172)
    ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nick.simplequiz.paid.component.CardShadowView" on path: /data/app/com.nick.simplequiz.paid-1.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
```

and this is the xml where I believe it has the issue at:

```
<com.nick.simplequiz.paid.view.CardView  //starting here
        android:id="@+id/carddemo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
```

What I do not understand is what is causing the error, I have verified that all of the classes were correctly copied and renamed, but I am not sure what else to try. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from an improper dependency, I know you said you checked it but it still can't find it, I would really try and follow the authors directions and try modifying the maven build file or this might just be the first of many errors

Comment: Thats what I previously had tried, but when I tried that I didn't understand the steps to doing it. Simply copying the dependency into my build.gradle file did not seem to do anything, I previously asked a question about it found here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943636/using-code-from-maven-project-in-intelij

Comment: are you using android studio or eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

The only step required to start using this project is to add the gradle dependencies in your build.gradle file (lowest in your directory tree).

```
dependencies { 
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.7.3' 
}
```